# Asking for advice on how to think about asset allocation

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I would like to ask a question on the main site but am not sure it's on-topic.

A year ago I hired a fee-based planner to design a retirement portfolio, and was happy with the results.  I elected not to sign up for their ongoing management, built my own spreadsheet models based on their reports, and set up my portfolio using their basic allocation approach.

After a year I'm looking to rebalance, and am second-guessing the  foreign allocations based on my own perception of the world market prospects for the next 10-15 years.

I want to ask, not for specific advice (i.e. NOT "what should I invest in") but rather what I should be considering when changing my allocation targets.

Is that on-topic?

Answer (score 2):

I would think yes but some may be inclined to see it as rather opinion-based as some may say, "Do what your strategy tells you to do," as the most common possible answer you'd get. Others may identify the risks like currency risk that you'd have which is likely what you want for answers I'd imagine. Thus, while I would like to see it asked, I suspect it would get closed in the end.

Answer (score 2):

> After a year I'm looking to rebalance, and am second-guessing the foreign allocations based on my own perception of the world market prospects for the next 10-15 years.

It depends on how you word the question. If you make it specific, i.e. you have X total in investments with x1, x2, x3 % in stocks, funds, gold, real estate, etc and should you diversify more or in general is there a standard bench mark on how much to diversify based on total investments .... this may be on topic. However if the question is "Should I invest more in Foreign Markets" its off-topic as its more of opinion.

> I want to ask, not for specific advice (i.e. NOT "what should I invest in") but rather what I should be considering when changing my allocation targets.

If you word it right, it may be on topic. Suggest ask any ways, the max is it would get closed down.